# Use KPSS test with all lags

Tags: python, lags, kpss-test

I have a series with `N` observation, I want to test the whole series for stationarity with KPSS. However I noticed that when run with all lags, the KPSS test always seems to return the `0.5` value, for example:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import kpss
kpss(np.random.uniform(0,1,100), nlags=99)
```

```
(0.499999999999999,
 0.04166666666666689,
 99,
 {'10%': 0.347, '5%': 0.463, '2.5%': 0.574, '1%': 0.739})
```

I'm surely missing something, my business requirement is to test the series for stationarity in the long period (meaning: the whole series) and in the short period (meaning: i.e. the latest 10 values), so I assumed to run the KPSS test with `nlags=N` and `nlags=10`.

Could you help me understanding what I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nlags` in `kpss` does not take a slice (window) of the time series. Instead, it specifies the autocorrelation structure for the estimation of the covariance matrix in the test. See [this](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.kpss.html) for details.

If you want to test for presence of a unit root in a slice (window) of the time series, do the slicing beforehand and then supply the result to the `kpss` function. Regarding `nlags` in `kpss`, keep it as `nlags='auto'` unless you have some additional information about the autocorrelation structure.